# Show location on map from address

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I want to show user location as per address submitted by him. For that i am using Geocoder. But i got following error.

```
10-17 18:21:02.734 1914-1934/com.example.googlemapdemo E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
10-17 18:21:02.735 1914-1934/com.example.googlemapdemo E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

I have get google api key by following all steps. Here is my code

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
String result=null;

try {
    List addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address.getText().toString(),1);

    if(addressList!=null && addressList.size() > 0) {
        Address address = (Address) addressList.get(0);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);

        double lat = address.getLatitude();
        double longti = address.getLongitude();

        Log.e("lat..long","lat...long"+lat+"....."+longti);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Lat",lat);
        intent.putExtra("Long",longti);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**map.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      tools:context="com.example.googlemapdemo.MapsActivity"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**MapActivity**

```
package com.example.googlemapdemo;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double lat, longt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        lat = getIntent().getIntExtra("Lat",0);
        longt = getIntent().getIntExtra("Long",0);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available. This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be
     * used. This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this
     * case, we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia. If Google Play services is not installed
     * on the device, the user will be prompted to install it inside the SupportMapFragment. This
     * method will only be triggered once the user has installed Google Play services and returned
     * to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(lat,longt);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

I also have added all permisions and api key to menifest

**AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemapdemo" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <permission
        android:name="package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <uses-permission android:name="package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Make sure that you're using the latest version of Google Play Services.

Comment: i have mentioned that in gradle and i think it is the latest one...i have also tried same in eclipse and it works fine...so it may be some dependency issue in studio

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the package name and SHA certificate fingerprint on the developers console, under your key. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add map key to show googlemap on your application.I didn't see it in the manifest file,i see only key for using GeoCoder

Try after adding your google map key. Example is shown below

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

Comment: still you have the issue?

Comment: Update your "Google play services" and see what happens

Comment: i have used latest one 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help you:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = null;
try {
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName("Location String", 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Address address = addresses.get(0);
if(addresses.size() > 0) {
    double latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
    double longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
}
```